# Posible problem with SPFx V1.0

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

In the instructions for HelloWorld WebPart "Connect to SharePoint"  under the heading "Retrieve List Data" is the following code :-

```
<div class="${styles.column}">
  <span class="${styles.title}">
    Welcome to SharePoint!
  </span>
  <p class="${styles.subtitle}">
    Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.
  </p>
  <p class="${styles.description}">
    ${escape(this.properties.description)}
  </p>
  <p class="${styles.description}">
    ${escape(this.properties.test2)}
  </p>
```

Unfortunately, styles.title, styles.subtitle, styles.description are not defined in HelloWorld.module.sccs So will not compile.

How do I fix this.  If I try and use the RC0 version, then it fails to compile :-

```
.title {
 @include ms-font-xl;
 @include ms-fontColor-white;
  }
```

fails to compile -

```
Error: no mixin named ms-font-l

           Backtrace:
            src/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorld.module.scss:20
            on line 20 of src/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorld.module.scss
    >>   @include ms-font-l;
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because those classes are missing from the HelloWorld.module.scss file.  I just added dummy classes and it compiled.  Below are the classes I added.  Note that this renders the information but *not* with the styling that is shown in the example.  Once you have the relevant styling just add it to the relevant classes below. - M

```
.column {
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .title {
    color: #333333;    
  }

  .subtitle {
    color: #333333;    
  }

  .description {
    color: #333333;    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vesa Juvonen - There was a typo in "Connect your client-side web part to SharePoint (Hello world part 2)" the first piece of code - here is the corrected code :-

```
this.domElement.innerHTML = `
  <div class="${styles.helloWorld}">
    <div class="${styles.container}">
      <div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${styles.row}">
        <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-u-lg10 ms-u-xl8 ms-u-xlPush2 ms-u-lgPush1">
          <span class="ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-white">Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
          <p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white">Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
          <p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white">${escape(this.properties.description)}</p>
          <p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white">Loading from ${escape(this.context.pageContext.web.title)}</p>
          <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" class="${styles.button}">
            <span class="${styles.label}">Learn more</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="spListContainer" />
  </div>`;

this._renderListAsync();
```